# Android, Dagger 2 inject recyclerview inside fragment

Tags: android, dagger-2

As I read before, dagger comes to emit all constructors and provide them by itself, so we should NOT have almost any constructor inside our business, now imagine there is a `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment` and the `Activity` is injecting the fragment, how can I inject `LayoutManager` and `Adapter` and also `Presenter` for fragment (without injecting them inside activity and pass through arguments to fragment)

The sample I'm working on is [here](https://github.com/frogermcs/GithubClient/tree/1bf53a2a36c8a85435e877847b987395e482ab4a), but he used `Activity` itself as `View` according to `MVP` pattern but I'm trying to use `Fragment` instead.

[This](https://github.com/frogermcs/GithubClient/blob/1bf53a2a36c8a85435e877847b987395e482ab4a/app/src/main/java/frogermcs/io/githubclient/ui/activity/RepositoriesListActivity.java) is his `Activity` (that recycler view and presenter are injected here).

My code:

UserComponent that is subComponent of AppComponent

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(modules = UserModule.class)
public interface UserComponent {
     RepoListComponent plus(RepoListModule repoListModule);

     UserEntity getUserEntity();
}
```

RepoListModule:

```
@Module
public class RepoListModule {
private RepoListContract.View view;

public RepoListModule(RepoListContract.View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Provides
RepoListContract.View provideRepoListContractView(){
    return view;
}

@Provides
LinearLayoutManager provideLayoutManager(Context context) {
    return new LinearLayoutManager(context);
}

@Provides
RepoListAdapter provideAdapter(RepoListContract.View view) {
    return new RepoListAdapter(view);
  }
}
```

RepoListComponent:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = RepoListModule.class)
public interface RepoListComponent {
    void inject(RepoListContract.View view);
}
```

RepoListActivity:

```
public class RepoListActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_repo_list);
    RepoListFragment fragment = (RepoListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new RepoListFragment();
        ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                fragment, R.id.fragment_container);
    }
    GApplication.get(getApplicationContext())
            .getUserComponent().plus(new RepoListModule(fragment))
            .inject(fragment);
  }
}
```

RepoListFragment:

```
public class RepoListFragment extends Fragment implements RepoListContract.View {
@BindView(R.id.rv_repo) RecyclerView rvRepo;

@Inject RepoListContract.Presenter presenter;
@Inject LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
@Inject RepoListAdapter adapter;

public static RepoListFragment newInstance() {
    return new RepoListFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_repo_list, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    initRvRepo();
    return v;
}
private void initRvRepo() {
    rvRepo.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); // null
    rvRepo.setAdapter(adapter); //null
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    presenter.subscribe(); //NullPointerException
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand these words: *"... so we should NOT have almost any constructor inside our business..."*. Usually I go by - As a rule of thumb every time you see the `new` operator that's an indication that you have a tight dependency on the class being instantiated and you should try to remove this. That said, here's how I would approach your task (There are  definitely way more solutions, this is just one approach).

Let's start from the simplest thing. Let's create your fragment:

```
public RepositoriesListFragment extends Fragment implements RepositoriesListView {
   @Inject RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
   @Inject RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
   @Inject RepositoriesListPresenter presenter;

   public static RepositoriesListFragment newInstance() {
       return new RepositoriesListFragment();
   }
   // ...
}
```

Now this could be the module for the dependencies:

```
@Module
public class RepositoriesListModule {
   private final RepositoriesListView view;

   public RepositoriesListModule(RepositoriesListView view) {
      this.view = view;
   }

   @Provides
   public RepositoriesListView providesView() {
      return view;
   }

   @Provides
   public RecyclerView.LayoutManager providesLayoutManager(Context context) {
     return new LinearLayoutManager(context);
   }

   @Provides
   public RecyclerView.Adapter providesAdapter(SomeAdapterImpl adapter) {
     return adapter;
   }

   @Provides
   public RepositoriesListPresenter providesPresenter(SomePresenterImpl presenter) {
      return presenter;
   }
}
```

First thing to notice is that it expects the view in the constructor. This is there because usually the presenter requires the view too. Hence `SomePresenterImpl` would expect this view in it's constructor.

Second thing, this module assumes the `Context` is also provided somewhere. Most likely through another module on which the component would depend on.

Here's the component:

```
@Component(modules = { RepositoriesListModule.class, ... })
public interface RepositoriesListComponent {
    void inject(RepositoriesListFragment fragment);
}
```

(As said before this component might require other modules or even depend on other components).

Last thing you need to do is inject the fragment. As you said, there's an activity creating and injecting the fragment. So this could look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // ...
      RepositoriesListFragment fragment = RepositoriesListFragment.newInstance();

      DaggerRepositoriesListComponent.builder()
         .repositoriesListModule(new RepositoriesListModule(fragment))
         .inject(fragment);
      // ...
   }
```

Like I said, this is not the only way of doing it. This has an issue, where you create the component several times. If you scope the component than you need to handle it's creation correctly. You cannot create it every time, otherwise you'll render the scope useless. The challenging part there is that the module needs the correct view every time you're going to inject the view, you need to make sure the module references that view.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

After having a look at your code I think the issue is related with the fact that you're adding the fragment before injecting, so essentially doing so might solve the issue:

```
public class RepoListActivity extends BaseActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_repo_list);
    RepoListFragment fragment = (RepoListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
       fragment = new RepoListFragment();
       GApplication.get(getApplicationContext())
        .getUserComponent().plus(new RepoListModule(fragment))
        .inject(fragment);
       ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(
            getSupportFragmentManager(),
            fragment, R.id.fragment_container);
    }
  }
}
```

Why is it happening? Looking at your `RepoListFragment` you're accessing the injected variables in both `onResume` and `onCreateView`. These are part of the fragment's lifecycle which will run once it's added to the activity (assuming `ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity` actually adds/replaces the fragment in the layout).

As you see, this means that before you have a chance to inject the members, you're already accessing them. So you should inject the fragment before you add it.

Comment: Are you saying that I can have access to adapter for example?? I did it but  not working

Comment: What do you mean you can access to the adapter? You create the adapter yourself...

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer but as `RepositoriesListComponent` is subcomponent of UserComponent that is AppComponent's subcomponent, it may happen, now my adapter and layoutManager are null! -> Activity: => 'GApplication.get(getApplicationContext())
                .getUserComponent().plus(new RepoListModule(fragment))
                .inject(fragment);'

Comment: Like I said, this is just one way of doing it. Sounds like you have another issue. I don't see a reason why at that time these would be null, so maybe you can update your question with some code you've tried already and I can change the answer to help you out.